# SQLAlchemy: Formatting a db.DateTime() column result

Tags: datetime, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a relative simple SQLAlchemy query (on an MySQL database):

```
my_date = db.session.query(func.max(MyTable.date_column)).one()
```

The queried column is of type `db.DateTime()`.

Now I want to format the returned date in `my_date`:

```
my_date.isoformat() # fails
my_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z") # fails
```

**What is this object I get as result and what do I have to do to get a datetime object that can be formatted?**

When I use the debugger to inspect the returned object I see the following: `(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 28, 12, 35, 17),)` - but a real Python datetime.datetime object looks different in the debugger.

`dir(my_date)` returns the following:

```
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__',
'__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', 
'__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', 
'__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__mul__', 
'__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmul__', 
'__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 
'_asdict', '_fields', '_real_fields', 'count', 'index', 'keys']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`one()` returns result as [KeyedTuple](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html?highlight=keyedtuple#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple).

You can use [scalar()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.scalar)

```
my_date = db.session.query(func.max(MyTable.date_column)).scalar()
```

or get value from tuple

```
my_date = db.session.query(func.max(MyTable.date_column)).one()[0]
```

Comment: This nowhere mentioned in the SQLAlchemy documentation - how should one know this? Are you sure it is an "KeyedTuple"? I only get the type `{result}`.

Comment: `type(my_date)` returns `sqlalchemy.util._collections.KeyedTuple`. And tutorial (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#querying) says that the tuples returned by Query are named tuples, supplied by the KeyedTuple class.

Comment: Looks like we use a different version, because `type(my_date)` on my system returns `<class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'>`

Comment: Yes, it returns `sqlalchemy.util._collections.KeyedTuple` in SQLAlchemy 0.9.9 and `sqlalchemy.util._collections.result` in 1.0.10. It looks like the same class, but i don't know why it's named `result`.